# VB Application to control a PLC

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors, plc

I am trying to control a Allen Bradley ControlLogix PLC from a Vb application using the vHMIABE driver from Allen Bradley and i keep getting this error :

http://imageshack.com/a/img842/4560/lqy2.png

This error appear when i click on my Connection button which use this following code :

```
    Private Sub PLC_Connect_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PLC_Connect.Click

    'Connection to PLC
    Display.Items.Clear()

    With Read_Bit
        .Control_PLCType = vHMIABE.enuPLCType.ControlLogix 'PLC of ControlLogix
        .Control_PLCIPAddress = "192.168.1.112"
        .Control_SocketNumber = 44818
        .Control_ResponseTimeOut = 5000 'The communication will timeout after 5 secondes
        .Memory_Function = vHMIABE.enuPLCMemoryFunction.Connect ' Connection

        .Control_UseAdvancedErrorReporting = True 'Description of error messages

        .Control_Update() ' Make the connection

    End With

    With Write_Bit

        .Control_PLCType = vHMIABE.enuPLCType.ControlLogix 'PLC of ControlLogix
        .Control_PLCIPAddress = "192.168.1.112"
        .Control_SocketNumber = 44818
        .Control_ResponseTimeOut = 5000 'The communication will timeout after 5 secondes
        .Memory_Function = vHMIABE.enuPLCMemoryFunction.Connect ' Connection

        .Control_UseAdvancedErrorReporting = True 'Description of error messages

        .Control_Update() ' Make the connection

    End With

End Sub
```

I tried to put comments as much as i can to make my code more understandable

Somebody have any ideas ?

Thanks so much per advance.

Comment: I know this is old but maybe others will find this helpful. Remember, a PLC is a controller (Programmable Logic Controller). So I think what your asking is how to interface with a ControlLogix PLC.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about this driver, but I can give you a more modern option based on .NET that is way easier to use. In fact a single line of code will write or read variables

http://www.advancedhmi.com

Code example to read:

```
EthernetIPforCLXCom1.Read("MyTag")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use a second .control_update before the first one has been completed. Must wait the Done event of the first .control_update sentence before execute a second one.